# How to config sbt maven dependency not including scala version

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, sbt

I want to include a maven module `mongo-hadoop-core` in a scala project.

Here is the .sbt file:

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.mongo-hadoop" %% "mongo-hadoop-core" % "1.5.0"
```

but when run `sbt package` and it will complain about not finding the mongo-hadoop-core_2.10 dependency:

```
[warn]  module not found: org.mongodb.mongo-hadoop#mongo-hadoop-core_2.10;1.5.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/ximing/.ivy2/local/org.mongodb.mongo-hadoop/mongo-hadoop-core_2.10/1.5.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/mongo-hadoop-core_2.10/1.5.0/mongo-hadoop-core_2.10-1.5.0.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.mongodb.mongo-hadoop#mongo-hadoop-core_2.10;1.5.0: not found
```

And I think this may because `sbt` try to include mongo-hadoop-core_2.10 instead of just mongo-hadoop-core package. It seemed sbt append a scala version arbitrarily (on the compatibility concern ?). How can I tell `sbt` not worry about that and just download and include the `mongo-hadoop-core` module anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.mongo-hadoop" % "mongo-hadoop-core" % "1.5.0"`.

The `%%` is what adds the Scala version to the name and is used for Scala libraries only.